# find variance of data array using php

Tags: php

I want to find variance of the values but i'm not able to find mean correctly. I added explode because while taking array_sum it was showing error that  array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given.

```
 <html><body>
  <?php
  $ap = '36.222.198.197.166.140'; 
  $counte =0;$sum=0;
  $file_handle = fopen("results.csv", "r"); 
  while ( $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle)){
  if ($line_of_text[2] == $ap) {
  $counte++;
   $van = explode(" ",$line_of_text[3]);
    $fMean = array_sum($van) / count($van);
   print_r ($van);
  }
  }
 fclose($file_handle);
?>
 </body></html>
```

Here is csv format- 
     time1, time2,  mac,    2.4ghz, 5ghz

```
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.166.140, -73,    -72
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.114, -69,    -65
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.194.95.70,   -74,    0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.227 0,  -63
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.171.88,  -73,    -69
1485874798, 1485878398, 24.100.114.205.236.242, 0,  0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.34.153 0,  0
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.118, -74,    -64
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.220 0,  -74
1485874798, 1485878398, 216.199.200.202.199.48, 0,  -67
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.193.105.60,  -62,    -66
1485874798, 1485878398, 156.28.18.195.202.230,  -74,    -74
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.126, -73,    -71
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.219 0,  -60
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.217,    -45,    -63
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.218,    -71,    -73
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.38.216,    0,  -74
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.33.193,    0,  0
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.190, -74,    0
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.166.138, -74,    -68
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.33.197,    0,  -72
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.171.18,  -74,    -74
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.33.58, 0,  0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.33.199,    -74, 0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.31.214,    -63,    -69
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.198, 0,  -69
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.31.218 -74,    0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.35.135,    0,  0
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.171.68,  -74,    -67
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.194.97.50,   -74,    0
1485874798, 1485878398, 216.199.200.202.200.152,    -74,    -74
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.193.134.238, -70,    0
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.35.131,    0,  -42
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.170.202, -73,    -73
1485874798, 1485878398, 148.180.15.200.220.78, -74, -70
1485874798, 1485878398, 36.222.198.197.170.100, -73,    -66
1485874798, 1485878398, 0.36.108.195.30.123, -74,   -66
```

Comment: Why do you explode field 3? It is just a number...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are explding in the 4th column for example on the last line of you csv you have `-74` and `-66` is `-66` in the column `2.4_thresh` or in `5_thresh`?

Comment: Column 2  row 1 is 36.222.198.197.166.140 i  want to count how many times it appears in csv but every time it is just showing 111 it should be count 3 but showing 111. i'm converting in an array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inconsistencies in your data:

- The first two lines have commas as separators, while the other lines have not.
- The second line has an IP address that ends with a dot.

The expression `explode(" ",$line_of_text[3]);` makes no sense, as `$line_of_text[3]` is a number, not something with spaces. It also does not make sense to use `count` on this result, as you want to count rows, not something in one of the fields.

Here is a corrected version:

```
$ap = '36.222.198.197.166.140'; 
$file_handle = fopen("results.csv", "r"); 
while ( $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle)){
    if ($line_of_text[2] == $ap) $van[] = $line_of_text[3];
}
fclose($file_handle);
$fMean = array_sum($van) / count($van);
```

The variance is then calculated like this:

```
$variance = array_sum(array_map(function ($x) use ($fMean) { 
    return pow($x - $fMean, 2);
}, $van)) / count($van);
```

Comment: But why would you want to perform an `array_sum` within the loop? You need to first build the array of all values, and do the sum *after* the loop on that array.

Comment: I'm performing in a loop because i have to use $van  or array at the time of variance calculation because for variance i'm using $fVariance += pow($line_of_text[3] - $fMean, 2);

Comment: It will be a wrong calculation if you try to calculate the variance when you have not determined the mean yet: for knowing the mean you need to first have finished *all* iterations of the loop. You don't have a valid mean *before* that. Did you check the code I have posted?

Comment: thanks, i know that i need to find fMean first that why i'm using that in variance too.But  if ($line_of_text[2] == $ap) in this condition if i need to find how many times $ap appears in csv but i'm not able to find that count value. count($van) this one.

Comment: Have you tested the solution I have provided? You just do `count($var)` after the loop. I have the impression you have not looked at my answer at all...

Comment: Thanks tricot, I did that before but i was missing something so getting error now it working for me. Thanks much!!

Comment: I want to ask you one more question which is like if i want to find variance of a list . i mean here i'm finding for a single mac if i want to find for multiplehow it will work?